# Determine intersection of bisector of 2 lines and a circle around the intersection of those 2 lines

Tags: geometry

Given the coordinates of three points `S`, `T` and `U` and a radius `r`, is there a simple formula to calculate the intersection of the bisector of `ST` and `SU` and the circle around `S` with radius `r`? In the image below, the coordinates of the point `P` are needed.

To make it more difficult, the vertical axis is upside-down.

How would I solve this easily?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more *analyitc* solution can be this one: the equations of the angle bisectors of the angle created by 2 lines whose implicit equations are $$a_1x+b_1y=c_1 \qquad(1)$$ $$a_2x+b_2y=c_2 \qquad(2)$$ can be found as $$\left( a_{1}\sqrt{a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}}-a_{2}\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}%
\right) x+\left( b_{1}\sqrt{a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}}-b_{2}\sqrt{%
a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}\right) y=c_{1}\sqrt{a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}}\pm c_{2}\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}\qquad
\left( 3\right)$$
In this case you have to find the lines $ST$ and $SU$, which are $$ ST : y=\frac{y_S-y_T}{x_S-x_T}\cdot(x-x_T)+y_T$$ and $$ SU : y=\frac{y_S-y_U}{x_S-x_U}\cdot(x-x_U)+y_U$$ extract the equation of the angle bisector, and solve the system 
\begin{cases}
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2 \\
a_3x+b_3y=c_3 \\
\end{cases}
where $a_3=\left( a_{1}\sqrt{a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}}-a_{2}\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}%
\right)$, $b_3 = \left( b_{1}\sqrt{a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}}-b_{2}\sqrt{%
a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}\right)$, and $c_3 = c_{1}\sqrt{a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}}\pm c_{2}\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}$

Comment: Note that the way you describe lines using slope, things will break if either $ST$ or $SU$ are vertical. Would you use the slop eform as a special case for that implicit equation? Personally I prefer something like $$\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\b_1\\-c_1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_S\\y_S\\1\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}x_T\\y_T\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ which avoids the slope formulation altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Think in vectors. Start with two difference vectors

$$
\overrightarrow{ST}=\overrightarrow T-\overrightarrow S \qquad
\overrightarrow{SU}=\overrightarrow U-\overrightarrow S
$$

Scale them so that the length becomes one:

$$\frac{\overrightarrow{ST}}{\lVert\overrightarrow{ST}\rVert} \qquad
\frac{\overrightarrow{SU}}{\lVert\overrightarrow{SU}\rVert}$$

Add them to obtain a point on the bisector, at least if you consider $S$ the origin:

$$\overrightarrow V :=
\frac{\overrightarrow{ST}}{\lVert\overrightarrow{ST}\rVert} +
\frac{\overrightarrow{SU}}{\lVert\overrightarrow{SU}\rVert}$$

Scale that vector to the desired length, i.e. $r$, then add that to $S$:

$$\overrightarrow P = \overrightarrow S +
\frac{r}{\lVert\overrightarrow V\rVert}\overrightarrow V$$

Comment: As I'm need to put this into a programming language, I'm going to select the answer of @steven as the correct answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @gieldl: Sure, choose whatever is most useful to you. I know that I'd prefer my own answer when implementing this as well. Solving a non-linear system of equations is something I might do with a CAS, but when writing code myself I'd rather avoid such steps if possible.